# Best way to check 2 mutually exclusive conditions with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, setinterval, states

Hi I have  the following code, that checks for Rails model status

```
var intervalCall = setInterval(function(){
  $.post("getstatus", {id:id});
  var finished = "<%= @sentence.finished%>";
     //THIS IS CONDITION ONE, IT IS LIKELY TO HAPPEN LATER AND I WANT TO STOP THE SETINTERVAL
  if ("<%= @sentence.result %>"){
        clearInterval(intervalCall);
        state_2();
  }
     //THIS IS CONDITION TWO, IT IS LIKELY TO HAPPEN EARLIER AND I WANT 
    // TO KEEP THE SETINTERVAL RUNNING AFTER IT"S MET
   else if (String(finished)== "true"){
        state_1();
    }
},3000);


intervalCall;
```

What would be the best way to organize this kind of flow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `String(finished)== "true"` o_O I propose to improve it to `String(finished).length == 4`

Comment: changed it but did not quite solve the problem..

Comment: @zerkms was being sarcastic, I guess... If `@sentence.finished` is going to be either `true` or `false`, you should be using `var finished = <%= @sentence.finished%>;` (no quotes), and `if (finished)` or `if(finished === true)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// setInterval/ setTimeout return the timer id
var intervalCall;
function updateStatus (){
    // post need a callback to process the data response by server
    $.post("getstatus", {id:id}, function  ( data ) {
        data = $.parseJSON ( data ) // asume you use jQuery and the data is a json string
        if ( data.result ){
            state_2(); // if you want the result as a arg, do state_2( data.result )
            return;
        } else {
            // no need to use finished flag, when there is a response and no result, call again
            // anything when no success resulte you want to do could write here

            state_1();
            intervalCall = setTimeout ( updateStatus, 3000 );
        }
    });
},3000);
intervalCall = setTimeout ( updateStatus, 3000 );
```

some update

Comment: Great, thanks! One problem is that I actually do need to call state_1 b/c there is another action that is getting triggered (by Rails controller) by the  $.post("getstatus", {id:id})  - and I need to keep that action triggered unless I have state_1 condition met.. Hope the explanation is clear enough.. Let me know otherwise please.

Comment: Also this line:       data = $.parseJSON ( data ) // asume you use jQuery and the data is a json string
gives "Unexpected token v" error

Comment: it actually worked with this solution (I still have to make a separate  $.get('/sentence/'+id+'.json, function(data){if(data.result){..}}); Thanks!